# Python sys.argv to accept HTML input

Tags: python, python-2.7

So currently I'm working with an applescript to pass a raw message from mail to python.
I'm calling shell to execute the python using applescript however the sys.argv seems having an issue in accepting the input, I think because the raw message is complicated because it is in HTML form. Any ideas or suggestion what can I used to accept a html data using sys.arv or any other alternative?

Answer (score 0):

Does it have to be `sys.argv`?

You can change the python script so that it reads in an html file instead.

If not, you could also add quotes on your arguments to escape html tags.

Example:

```sh
 $ python3 test.py "<html><p>foo</p></html>"
['test.py', '<html><p>foo</p></html>']
```

Where the contents of **test.py** are:

```py
import sys
if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(sys.argv)
```